# Sybase use parameter as where clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, parameters, sybase, where-clause

I have a dynamic set of conditions that are used in a where clause.

I'm trying to add them into a stored procedure in the WHERE clause as a parameter for the full clause but not getting results back.

Is this possible?

```
Parameter @sql_statement = 'date in ('2011-01-01','2012-01-01','2012-05-24') AND doc = '1''

#where statement
WHERE emp='x' AND @sql_statement
```

Comment: Parameters can't be part of the SQL, they're data items and will always be data items.  You would need to use the parameter to build a new SQL command and execute than new command *(Dynamic SQL)*.

Comment: Which version of Sybase are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Dems](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53341/dems) mentioned, it looks like you want to use [dynamic SQL](http://sybasease.blogspot.com/2005/05/dynamic-sql.html).

You might try:

```
declare @where_clause varchar(100)
declare @sql_statement varchar(500)
select @where_clause = 'date in (''2011-01-01'',''2012-01-01'',''2012-05-24'') AND doc = ''1'''
select @sql_statement = 'select * from my_table where ' + @where_clause
exec (@sql_statement)
```