# Sybase - Use parameter for IN clause

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters, sybase, optional-parameters

I need a way to perform the following pattern in Sybase:

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE x IN (@list)

The select would be a part of a stored procedure that is passed values from a web form. I would like to allow users to enter 0 to many search keys for each field, where multiple values are entered separated by some delimiter. Currently I can handle 0 to 1 keys, but not >1.

I've been trying to find an elegant solution for this similar to the pseudo SQL above, and while I have found other DBs seem to have a built in way to support (arrays for example) this it doesn't seem there is a simple answer for Sybase.

Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if more details would help.

Comment: The elegant solution is a db that takes an array or a CTE. Without them, this will have the grace of of a drunken elephant on stilts. You can pass in a comma delimited values as an argument and then chop it up in to a temporary table and use join instead of in.

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck with the current technology stack we have. I think chopping up a string into a temp table might be the most robust way, as terrible as that will be.

Comment: At least it hides the mess in the front end code, and you can blame the DBA if it goes wrong. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this in SQL.  The best alternative is to do string comparisons:

```
select *
from tbl
where ','+@list+',' like '%,'+x+',%'
```

Or, if you create the statement as dynamic SQL, then you can incorporate the list into the SQL query string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
declare @list varchar(100)

select @list = '1,2,3,4,5'

exec('SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE x IN ('+@list+')')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sub select and `sa_split_list` system procedure to split list into separate values.

Excerpt from the [documentation](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbreference/sa-split-list-sysproc.html):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProductsWithColor( IN color_list LONG VARCHAR )
BEGIN
  SELECT Name, Description, Size, Color
  FROM Products
  WHERE Color IN ( SELECT row_value FROM sa_split_list( color_list ) )
END;
go

SELECT * from ProductsWithColor( 'white,black' );
```

Or use `INNER JOIN` instead of `WHERE` for filtering

```
  SELECT Name, Description, Size, Color
  FROM Products
  INNER JOIN sa_split_list( color_list ) FILTER ON FILTER.row_value = Products.Color
```

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a very similar question with php and mysql, but I feel the answer applies equally here, so I'll copy/paste it.

I just handled the same problem, only in Visual Studio. First I created a string of parameters to add into the SQL statement. You only have to deal with question marks (?), so much of what I did is more than you need:

```
string[] inClause = new string[keywordTerms.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < keywordTerms.Length; i++)
    inClause[i] = ":keyword" + i.ToString("00");
```

Then when creating my select, I put the following in:

```
sqlStatement += "WHERE kw.keyword IN (" + String.Join(", ", inClause) + ")"
```

Finally, I added the parameters in this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < keywordTerms.Length; i++)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(inClause[i], OracleDbType.Varchar2, 20, "keyword").Value = keywordTerms[i];
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's too late but here is what I found when I encountered similar use case and it really helped me.

[[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101106/sybase-use-parameter-as-where-clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101106/sybase-use-parameter-as-where-clause)

Cheers